# What is the difference between this index.html and index-async.html in the Angularjs seed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

In the angularjs seed, there are 2 files which seem to have the same outcome. index.html and index-async.html

https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/index-async.html

https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/index.html

What is the difference between the 2 when the effect seems to be the same? My preference is index.html because the code looks more readable. What are the advantages of using index-async.html which is more unreadable?

Comment: you'd be viewing index-async.html from index.html after clicking some link. That is index-async.html is a kind of view page.

Comment: May I ask what is wrong with the question to get 2 downvotes? Would like to know so that I can improve this question and future questions. Thanks.

Comment: Question should be related to code in SO. (I'm not a downvoter)

Comment: Thanks. It will be more useful for those who downvote to explain their decisions. I am left wondering why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index-async "loads all of the dependencies asynchronously". It has nothing to do with readability. It's about performance and different use cases.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. Is it a good idea to use the faster index-async.html by default?

Comment: NO. index.html is to be default viewing page.

Comment: It has noting to do with performance. Both files servers different purposes.

Comment: @dfsq, with all due respect, loading dependencies asynchronously has both to do with different use cases and performance, for each case. The two do not exclude each other.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Okay you are right of course, but to say that performance is the reason why there is index-async.html is to say basically nothing about difference with two workflows. It's like to say that requireJS is for performance optimization.

Comment: @dfsq I see your point and you are right. There's a lot more than performance involved. I have reformulated my answer.